# MPAndroidChart for Swift - how to remove grid?

Tags: ios, swift, mpandroidchart

How can I do this? I tried to find method in Xcode, but I couldn't - in android documentation they have different names

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
  chartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
  chartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
  chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```